# cmd.exe equivalent of /dev/stdout, to write to stdout 'as a file'

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that calls a Windows GUI application. The GUI app writes it's output (the interesting bits anyway) to it's own GUI display rather than stdout, however I would like it displayed in the cmd window where the batch file is running.

Thankfully the app has an option to write the output to a file, so I need to redirect this to stdout. In *nix I would give `/dev/stdout` as the file to write to but what about in Windows/cmd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Windows has no equivalent to unix /dev/stdout.

Take a look at this thread:
https://superuser.com/questions/241272/windows-how-to-redirect-file-parameter-to-stdout-windows-equivalent-of-dev-st

Answer (score 2):

con is the equivalent of /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr in Windows. But I am not sure how you are writing the output. It will help if you could paste the block that writes to the file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, it does seem that it might be possible using CON but I've had no luck so far. Unfortunately the application isn't mine so I can't paste the code block.

Comment: how do you use CON?

Comment: Try to put `con:` where you would have put `/dev/stdout` but this is probably unlikely to actually work.